# Question on Finite Index Additive Subgroups of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'd like to understand the relationship between finite index additive subgroups of rings and finite index ideals. Namely, given a ring $R$ with a finite index additive subgroup $H \leq (R, +)$, can you always find an ideal $I \subseteq H$ such that $I$ is of finite index in $R$?

While I don't expect this to be true for general rings, many of the prototypical examples of rings do have this property. In $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of additive subgroups is exactly the set of finite index ideals. It also doesn't take much effort to find this property in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[m] n]$ for any $n, m \in \mathbb{Z},\; m > 0$ . My question: Is there some simple condition of a ring $R$ sufficient for this property to hold?

I've tried the typical restrictions for rings, like considering only those that are commutative domains, but I still can't get any one condition to stick. I think the key might be considering principal ideal domains, but I don't know how to proceed from there.